# Error while updating ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates

I am using ubuntu 16.04 in my Dell laptop and since some time I am getting an error message

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

while updating using command `sudo apt update`. I don't know exactly why this is happening. please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the directory "/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/" and remove the contents from it. Then try to run the update, I think this will solve your problem.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this command and it is showing "rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*': No such file or directory"